# Table drag and AHAH

Tags: ajax

I got a new content type in my own module  for Drupal 6. I want the user to create lists with some entries. For this, I tried to build a draggable table with an AHAH button to add a new row to this table.

In `hook_form()`, I add some items with the following code.

```
$form['listsWrapper'] = array(
 '#weight' => 5,
 '#tree' => true,
 '#prefix' => '<div id="lists-wrapper">',
 '#suffix' => '</div>',
);

$form['listsWrapper']['tableItem'] = array(
 '#type' => 'item',
 '#value' => '',
);

$entries = array();
$entries[] = array( 'name' => 'TestName #1' );
$entries[] = array( 'name' => 'TestName #2' );
$entries[] = array( 'name' => 'TestName #3' );
$entries[] = array( 'name' => 'TestName #4' );

foreach ($entries as $key => $value) {
  $form['listsWrapper']['lists'][] = array(
   'entry' => array(
     '#type' => 'textfield', 
     '#default_value' => $value['name'],
     '#maxlength' => 255,
    ),
    'weight' => array(
     '#type' => 'weight',
     // '#default_value' => $key,
     '#attributes' => array('class' => 'weight-group'),
    ),
    'parent' => array(
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#attributes' => array('class' => 'parent'),
     '#size' => 10
    ),
    'source' => array(
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#default_value' => $key,
     '#attributes' => array('class' => 'source'),
     '#size' => 10
    ),
  );
}

# ahah callback button
$form['listsWrapper']['more'] = array(
 '#type' => 'submit', 
 '#value' => t('Eine weitere Liste / einen weiteren Listeneintrag hinzufügen'), 
 '#weight' => 1, 
 '#submit' => array(), 
 '#ahah' => array(
  'path' => ahah_helper_path(array('listsWrapper')), 
  'wrapper' => 'lists-wrapper', 
  'method' => 'replace', 
 ),
);
```

In the theme function for this form, I add a table drag behavior to these elements.

```
function theme_cm_node_form($form) {
  $output = '';

  if(isset($form['listsWrapper'])) {
    drupal_add_tabledrag('draggable-lists-table', 'match', 'parent', 'parent', 'parent', 'source', TRUE, 1);
    drupal_add_tabledrag('draggable-lists-table', 'order', 'sibling', 'weight-group', NULL, NULL, TRUE);

    $header = array(t('Listeneintrag'), t('Gewichtung'));
    $rows = array();
    $lists = array();
    $entries = array();

    foreach (element_children($form['listsWrapper']['lists']) as $key) {
      $element = &$form['listsWrapper']['lists'][$key];

      if ($element['parent']['#value'] == '') {
        //parent
        $i = 0;
        while(isset($lists[$element['weight']['#value']+$i])) $i++;
        $pos = $element['weight']['#value']+$i;

        $lists[$pos] = $key;

      }
      else {
        //entry
        $i = 0;
        while (isset($entries[ $element['parent']['#value'] ][ $element['weight']['#value']+$i ])) {
          $i++;
        }

        $pos = $element['weight']['#value']+$i;
        $entries[ $element['parent']['#value'] ][$pos] = $key;
      }
    }

    ksort($lists);

    foreach ($lists as $list) {
      $element = &$form['listsWrapper']['lists'][$list];
      $row = array();

      $row[] = drupal_render($element['entry']);
      $row[] = drupal_render($element['weight']) . drupal_render($element['parent']) . drupal_render($element['source']);
      $rows[] = array('data' => $row, 'class' => 'draggable');

      ksort($entries[$list]);
      foreach ($entries[$list] as $entry) {
        $elementEntry = &$form['listsWrapper']['lists'][$entry];
        $row = array();

        $row[] = theme('indentation', 1) . drupal_render($elementEntry['entry']);
        $row[] = drupal_render($elementEntry['weight']) . drupal_render($elementEntry['parent']) . drupal_render($elementEntry['source']);
        $rows[] = array('data' => $row, 'class' => 'draggable');
      }
    }    

    if(!count($rows)) {
      $rows[] = array(array('data' => t('Derzeit sind noch keine Listeneinträge erstellt.'), 'colspan' => 2));
    }

    $form['listsWrapper']['tableItem']['#value'] = theme('table', $header, $rows, array('id' => 'draggable-lists-table'));
  }

  $output .= drupal_render($form);

  return $output;
}
```

Now I got something like this.

[image: my draggable table]

I can rearrange the rows and indent them (so they become a entry instead of a new list).
My problem is that the theme function isn't called after my AHAH callback, so my form looks like this.

[image: my table after ahah callback]

How can I invoke the theme function after my ahah callback? Do I have to invoke the JavaScript functions which will hide the weight field and so on again?

Comment: All I know is that in Drupal 7 it always happened to me automagically. And given that 6 will soon reach it's end of support, isn't it time to upgrade? Just asking.

Comment: Yes of course, I'd love to work with drupal 7. But my company is using D6, so this module have to work there.

Comment: I was sure this was backported. Sad to see it isn't. Unless you are not using 6.28 - it wasn't there in 6.18 as far as I remember. Could you show how does your ahah function look like? Can't you re-apply theming function in it and return themed part?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 6.28
For my ahah functions I use the [ahah_helper module](https://drupal.org/project/ahah_helper) to do the ahah callbacks. Maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I bypassed my problem by using [jQuery Nestable](http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/). I got a hidden form element and on every change in my Nestable list I put a json string in the hidden field. Much easier than using drupal tabledrag and ahah (also looks a bit better in the user front end). Here is what i got now:

[image: jQuery Nestable list]

Works fine for me.